# How to use > or < in Header name in SQL query?

Tags: java, sql, csvjdbc

I'm facing a problem while validating a csv file. I'm using the csvJdbc api for validating csv. But in CSV, there is a header which contains the '>' sign. When I try to use that header for validation, it throws an exception. 
Is there any way to use that ,like some escape character?
This is the query I'm trying to run:

```
SELECT *  FROM Temp_ where  SIDE_A_IVD_BIN12(>60)>=0

 SIDE_A_IVD_BIN10(50)    SIDE_A_IVD_BIN11(60)    SIDE_A_IVD_BIN12(>60)      
           0                         0                  0
           0                         0                  0
           0                         0                  0
           0                         0                  0
```

Comment: Please add a minimal example to reproduce the error.

Comment: Could you provide some data from the csv file, your java code and the exception/stacktrace?

Comment: Is provided info necessary???

Comment: In SQL Object names shall be used either with [] or "". Maybe that helps

Comment: @frlan: **SQL *Server***  uses the non-standard `[..]` quoting style. **SQL** (the query language) uses double quotes `"`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You are right. At least for some other as ASE you can turn it on to make it work. ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQL Server also supports SQL compliant quoting (and AFAIK it works out of the box without additional settings).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding braces around the query?

```
CREATE TABLE Temp_ (
    [SIDE_A_IVD_BIN12(>60)] int
)

INSERT INTO Temp_ VALUES (-1)
INSERT INTO Temp_ VALUES (0)
INSERT INTO Temp_ VALUES (1)

SELECT * FROM Temp_ WHERE [SIDE_A_IVD_BIN12(>60)] >= 0
```

Comment: ...assuming SQL Server, which to be fair is usually what people mean when they don't specify the SQL database.

Comment: How do you know Surinder is using SQL Server?

Comment: The [CsvJdbc documentation](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/doc.html) says: "Use double quotes around table names or column names containing spaces or other special characters."

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your DBMS, but in standard SQL (and nearly all DBMS) identifiers that contain special characters need to be enclosed in double quotes:

```
SELECT *  
FROM Temp_ 
where  "SIDE_A_IVD_BIN12(>60)" >= 0;
```

Edit (after realizing that the "DBMS" is `CsvJdbc`):

[The CsvJdbc manual](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/doc.html) (thanks @Gord for the link) also states that it's using the SQL standard syntax for quoting identifiers that contain special characters.

The above syntax works for me:

[image]

But I could not get CsvJdbc to treat the numbers as numbers, that's why I used `= '1'`

Comment: @SurinderRajpal This answer is correct. The [CsvJdbc documentation](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/doc.html) says: "Use double quotes around table names or column names containing spaces or other special characters." I just tested it with `csvjdbc-1.0-21.jar` and it does work.